# strcpy seems to take multiple arguments from docs

Tags: c

I looked up the documentation within the IDE, and seems that strcpy is taking multiple args ... although I also see two argument definition as well.

It'd be great to have something that can take multiple args for both copy and concat (strcat) as it will help to make the code brief.

**Question**, is it possible with built-in library or am I limited to two arguments only?

```
#if __has_builtin(__builtin___strcpy_chk) || defined(__GNUC__)
#undef strcpy
/* char *strcpy(char *dst, const char *src) */
#define strcpy(dest, ...) \
        __builtin___strcpy_chk (dest, __VA_ARGS__, __darwin_obsz (dest))
#endif
```

example code

```
char *first = "first";
char *second = "second";

char *message = malloc (sizeof(first) + strlen(second) + 1);
strcpy (message, first);
strcat (message, second);
```

documentation screenshot

[image]

Comment: That is not documentation, that's a macro that calls the built-in implementation.

Comment: `sizeof(first)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of `"first"`.  A pointer is not an array.  An array is not a pointer.

Comment: Those are compiler specific builtins, not portable and not intended for public consumption, and they don't take additional string arguments, anyway. See gcc's [Object Size Checking Built-in Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Object-Size-Checking.html).

Comment: "it possible with built-in library or am I limited to two arguments only?" --> Not limited. 
 `sprintf(message, "%s%s%s", first, second, third);` A good compiler can analyse and emit efficient code.

Comment: that looks like a header file, not "documentation"

Comment: Why do you post a picturscreen shot of the same text you've posted a few lines above?? Anyway: don't post pictures of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really, truly (for some reason) want to call a single function to produce a string that contains two (or more!) other strings, you could call one of the `sprintf` functions:

```c
sprintf(message, "%s%s", first, second)
```

(As also mentioned in the comment bu @chux)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stdarg.h` library. Functions that can take multiple arguments are called Variadic Functions and you can read more [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html#Variadic-Functions). Apparently, though, the C implementation is not type-safe and not recommended, but C++ makes it safer and easier with Variadic Templates.